# RecyclerView NotifyItemInserted() is NOT working on second time

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I am using RecyclerView NotifydataInserted() in my code to update a  chat by Firebase realtime database. On first attempt when i come to the chat activity page it works fine but as i go on and press back button to close the activity and again come to the chat activity page it stopped working but by database is updating the values correctly.

Comment: Would you please share your code that you have added?

Comment: My problem is solved as I was using firebase listener on a particular node on many instances but not cancelling it so it made the notifyadapter to run only once. it is solved by removing the nodes from other instances.